# Sign out not visible on homepage of magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I cant see default Sign out link after user sign-in on headers of my magento2.3 website.

Comment: Did you used custom theme?

Comment: @RohanHapani yes

Comment: Can you please upload your theme's authorization.phtml file code ?

Comment: @RohanHapani $dataPostParam = '';
if ($block->isLoggedIn()) {
    $dataPostParam = sprintf(" data-post='%s'", $block->getPostParams());
}
?>
<li class="authorization-link" data-label="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('or')) ?>">
    <a <?=$block->getLinkAttributes() ?><?=  $dataPostParam ?>>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLabel()) ?>
    </a>
</li>

Comment: @RohanHapani any suggestions?